# Angular2: Dependencies Between Apps created with angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-cli

I am using the [Angular2-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to create two applications: `MyFirstApp` & `MySecondApp`. I whish `MySecondApp` to import `MyFirstApp` so I can reuse directive/service/component.
When I import `MyFirstApp`, I have the following compilation error: `Cannot find module 'MyFirstApp'`.

Here's how to *reproduce*:

```
    $ npm -v
    3.9.3

    $ node -v
    v6.2.1

    $ npm list  | grep 'angular'
    ├── @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.1
    ├── @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.1
    ├── @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1
    ├── @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.1
    ├── @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.1
    ├── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.1
    ├── @angular/router@2.0.0-rc.1
    ├─┬ angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.5

    $ ng new MyFirstApp
    $ cd MyFirstApp
    $ ng g service MyFirstAppService
    $ ng build
    $ cd ..
    $ ng new MySecondApp
    $ cd MySecondApp
    $ npm install ../MyFirstApp --save #Also tried w/ ng install ../MyFirstApp and github link
    $ vim src/app/my-second-app.component.ts
```

Modify `src/app/my-second-app.component.ts` so it looks like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyFirstAppService } from 'MyFirstApp';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'MySecondApp',
  templateUrl: 'mysecondapp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['mysecondapp.component.css']
})
export class MySecondAppAppComponent {
  title = 'MySecondApp works!';
}
```

I tried *many* version of `import { MyFirstAppService } from 'MyFirstApp';` (i.e. `import { MyFirstAppServiceService } from './../../node_modules/my-first-app/src/app/my-first-app-service.service';`
& co) and played with `system-config.ts` (using [this](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/50#issuecomment-165448962) and [this](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library)) without any luck. I always have a `Cannot find module 'MyFirstApp'`.

Any suggestions ?

**Edit**:
By tweaking `system-config.ts` (lines 1 to 14) as follows:

```
const map: any = {
  'my-first-app': 'vendor/my-first-app/app/index.js'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'my-first-app': {
    format: 'cjs'
  }
};
```

I can do `import { MyFirstAppServiceService } from 'my-first-app/src/app/my-first-app-service.service';`. `.../dist/...` doesn't work. Doesn't seems to be the *right* way to do it though... Should'nt it be possible to do `import { MyFirstAppServiceService } from 'my-first-app/my-first-app-service.service'` ?

Note that the resulting `vendors/my-first-app/` directory doesn't contain the code of `MyFirstApp`

```
$ # While in MySecondApp
$ tree dist/vendor/my-first-app 
dist/vendor/my-first-app
├── angular-cli-build.js
└── config
    ├── environment.js
    ├── karma.conf.js
    ├── karma-test-shim.js
    └── protractor.conf.js
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developers of the Angular2-cli project want to support library/addons [flavoured project for the 1.0.0 release](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1095#issuecomment-226807127).

For now, what we can do to make it works:

1. Add a main in the library package.json
2. npm install yourlib --save in your other apps
3. Configure your second app so it packages your lib according to your needs. An example with gulp:

   var copyScripts = require('ionic-gulp-scripts-copy');

   ```
   gulp.task('assets', function(){
     return copyScripts({src:'node_modules/your-lib/dist/**/*', dest:'our-dest'});
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In your src/app/mysecondapp.component.ts, try to replace :

```
import { MyFirstAppService } from 'MyFirstApp';
```

By this

```
import { MyFirstAppService } from './app/MyFirstApp';
```

I hope it'll work :)

Comment: Nop. `Cannot find module './app/MyFirstApp'.`