# Angular CLI addon

Tags: angular, angular-cli

The Ember CLI has a command (`ember addon <addon-name>`) that will scaffold a new project designed to be installed via npm into other Ember CLI projects. These "addon" projects can also be built and served standalone using a built-in "dummy app", which acts as a fake consumer of the addon for testing and demonstration purposes. This is extremely useful for quickly creating a styleguide/component library that is shared between business apps but also deployed independently.

I am looking for an equivalent for my Angular CLI projects, and was hopeful the CLI would provide a similar method for creating addons, seeing as it is based on the Ember CLI. **Is it possible to consume an Angular CLI app from another Angular CLI app**, or will I have to create my own "addon" using a manual (gulp/grunt) build process?

Thanks!

*Related to [Angular2: Dependencies Between Apps created with angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822540/angular2-dependencies-between-apps-created-with-angular-cli) which is unsolved.*

Comment: Your "Related to" is marked as solved now: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38000951/1762493

Also, see this related answer from another SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35900837/1762493

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this writing, `angular-cli` does not have a direct equivalent of `ember`'s `addon`. However, as I've written in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44682375/754842), "`@angular/cli`'s commands support multiple applications with the `--app` flag. `ng serve --app foo` will serve the `foo` app, whereas `ng serve --app bar` will serve the `bar` app. This flag also works with `ng build`, `ng e2e`, `ng eject`, `ng test`, and `ng xi18n`. To add a new app to your existing `$ROOT` directory, use `ng new`." The applications may be configured in `.angular-cli.json`.