# Angular-cli ignores tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, angular

Using

```
"@angular/cli": "^1.0.0"
```

`@angular/cli` ignores `tsconfig.json`

The project compiles just fine editing / removing `tsconfig.json`

Why is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stupid as it may seem, the angular-cli 's `tsconfig.json` file is located inside `src/tsconfig.app.json`

The root `tsconfig.json` will be used by editors (such as vscode).

Comment: you can tell your editor to use the `src/tsconfig.app.json` why have two separate ones?

Comment: @AhmedMusallam angular-cli seems to create two of them by default

Comment: Actually 3 of them in angular-cli 1.0.0 for app, e2e and test i believe. Regardless, my point was about creating 2 tsconfig files for app.

Comment: @AhmedMusallam I'm not sure why Angular team did it this way. But, you generally want to have different config files if you share different config. In this case, `src/tsconfig.app.json` would be more specific configuration. This answer's intention isn't to change what they did though, but rather to point out the right configuration file.

Comment: you can have as many as you want. As long as you can justify it. In their case i believe it has to do with how they transpile .ts test files vs app files.

Comment: Wow this is something I really wasn't aware of. The best way to avoid duplication then is to declare another one in src/tsconfig.app.json that just extends from the one located one folder above

Answer (score 8):

The reason that your project compiles *without* `$ROOT/tsconfig.json` is that `@angular/cli` supports *multiple* apps within the root directory; your (single) app is compiling with `$ROOT/src/tsconfig.app.json` and your test suite with `$ROOT/src/tsconfig.spec.json`. The root `tsconfig.json` applies to *all* apps within the directory. Deleting it simply removed the *global* `tsconfig` that could potentially be used with many apps.

For a clearer understanding of this, look at `.angular-cli.json`. One property, `app`, supports an array of multiple applications, but the default configuration is for one application alone. As described in `@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json`, `app` supports "properties of the different applications in this project."

```json
"app": [{
  "root": "src"
  ...
  "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
  "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json"
}]
```

Using this array, you could have as many Angular apps as you like, each with its own specific TypeScript settings.

Additionally, `@angular/cli`'s commands support multiple applications with the `--app` flag. `ng serve --app foo` will serve the `foo` app, whereas `ng serve --app bar` will serve the `bar` app. This flag also works with `ng build`, `ng e2e`, `ng eject`, `ng test`, and `ng xi18n`. To add a new app to your existing `$ROOT` directory, use `ng new`.

The root `tsconfig` is not just for code editors and `tslint`. It applies globally to all apps in your project. How this works under the hood is rather complex, as is clear from [the source code](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/search?p=1&q=tsconfig.json&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93), where there are numerous json files that have lines such as `"extends": "../../../tsconfig.json"`.

Comment: Very helpful. Due to the custom name of `tsconfig.app.json` do you know if it is possible to manually compile with a tsc command from root that emulates ng build?